# MySQL: About BigData

Tags: mysql

So here's the deal. I've designed as schema which stores the daily stock quotes data. I've two tables (among others) "todayData" and "historicalData" with the same structure. The two tables have innodb engine as their storage engine. There is no FK between two tables and are independent.

if i need to see data for today, i query today table and if i need to generate reports or trending analysis etc i rely on historical table. During midnight, today's data will move to historical table.

The question is historical will be mammoth in few weeks (> 10 GB and counting) and needless to say serving this data from a single table is mindless.

What should i do to make sure the reports generate off of historical will be fast and responsive.

People have suggested partitioning etc but i would like to know are there any other ways to do this?

Thank you

Bo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no silver bullet for Big Data. All depends on the data and data usage (access patterns, etc.). First, make sure the table is properly indexed, your queries are optimal, and you have enough memory. And if you still have too much data to contain on single server, shard/partition (but mind the access patterns when you choose shard key - if you have to query multiple partitions for single report, it's bad. Buf if you really have to, make sure you can query them in parallel - something not possible currently with the build-in partitioning (so you need app-level sharding logic))

Comment: Thank you Darhazer. Can you please suggest some articles/manuals/books to approach this?